# Matplotlib: Direct way to get axes-coordinates of annotation boxes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Take a random scatter plot with annotations that have random offsets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpp
import random as rd

X = [1,3,2,5,4,2,3,1,2,3]
Y = [4,1,3,2,6,5,2,5,1,5]
L = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

fig,ax = mpp.subplots()
ax.scatter(X,Y)
for i,txt in enumerate(L):
    r1 = rd.choice([-10,5])
    r2 = rd.choice([-10,5])
    a = ax.annotate(txt,(X[i],Y[i]),size=8,textcoords='offset points',xytext=(r1,r2))
fig.show()
```

I tried to find the axis coordinates of those annotations but I didn't have any luck, most variables of the text-instance weirdly enough only return the offset:

```
print(ax.texts[0].xy)
print(ax.texts[0].xyann)
print(ax.texts[0]._x,ax.texts[0]._y)
print(ax.texts[0].get_position())
print(ax.texts[0].get_unitless_position())
print(ax.texts[0]._get_xy_display())
print(ax.texts[0].clipbox)
```

Returns:

```
(1, 4)
(-10, 5)
-10 5
(-10, 5)
(-10.0, 5.0)
[-10.   5.]
None
```

I know that I can get the axes-coordinates using a transform like this:

```
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
bb = ax.texts[0].get_window_extent()
co = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(bb)
```

But I'd prefer it if there was a direct way of getting them, especially since I can't believe the axes coordinates aren't written somewhere within that text-instance since userland- and display-coordinates are in there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea of using a different coordinate system, like "offset points" here, is that the display coordinates are not actually known before drawing the respective artist. And they don't need to be known. There is no reason that the artist needs to store its position in some other coordinate system then the one of its transform - that's the idea behind the transforms.

So to answer the question: No, the display coordinates are not stored anywhere and thus also not the axes coordinates.

Of course you can ask to calculate them like you did with `get_window_extent()` and then to get axes coordinates apply the inverse axes transform.

Comment: But how does the display coordinates being unknown explain the axes coordinates to be unknown? Since the axes and the figure coordinates are relative coordinates between 0 and 1 they are independent of the display size and could easily be saved in some variable. The `ax.get_position()` for axes does return exactly the figure coordinates of the axes, but the same method for text-objects only returns the offset `xyann` from the initial position in userland coordinates `xy`.

Comment: Since the text is positionned in offset points, its coordinates are in offset points. So the transform chain would be offset->data->display->axes. I don't see what the axes storing its figure coordinates (which is useful because they define the axes' position) would have to do with the text. Or in other words, if you define the axes' position in offset coordinates, it would not know its figure coordinates either.

Comment: If I'd define my axes' position in offset coordinates it would still be offset from some defined point and getting the figure coordinates should be easy.
The other thing that bothers me is that you have to transform via display here. Why is it not possible to directly transform from data to axes?

Comment: This sounds more like you're questioning the way matplotlib is designed than to get a problem solved. Of course building a plotting library like matplotlib involves certain decisions being made between multiple possible designs and there would certainly be different ways to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the rationale behind it because it differs from what I'm expecting, and those expectations then lead me to design my code the wrong way.

Comment: I suppose you have read the [transformation tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)? To transform from data to axes you would chain the two transforms `t = transData + transAxes.inverted()`. Apart I'm now a bit lost as to what exact problem you're trying to solve.